# List two next nodes according to current one

Tags: views, 8, datetime

I need to add Views block on node page of one content type and there I need to show two next nodes by date (older than current) according to the date of current node's creation date.

How I can accomplish this?

Comment: nodes by date (older than current) according to the date of current node's creation date. you can achieve this by view ..

Comment: yes, exactly, as I wrote, but how? I need some help here...